# How to write data into a given excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Today i'm trying to write into a given excel sheet. Im using Java and apache poi. I want to write data into a given excel sheet. It's mean im trying to override lots data on the given sheet.
Here is my output
[image]

And here is the given excel sheet
[image]
Here is my code

```
 public class ExportExcelService {

    private final XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private  XSSFSheet sheet;
    private List<LocalDate> listLocalDate;
    private List<LocalDate> listHolidays;
    private Long year;
    private Long month;
    private User user;



    public ExportExcelService(List<LocalDate> listLocalDate, Long year, Long month,User user,List<LocalDate> listHolidays) {
        this.user = user;
        this.listLocalDate = listLocalDate;
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.listHolidays= listHolidays;
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    }
    private void writeHeaderLine() {
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Posts");
        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setBold(true);
        font.setFontHeight(16);
        style.setFont(font);
        YearMonth yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(this.year.intValue(), this.month.intValue());
        int daysInMonth = yearMonthObject .lengthOfMonth();
        createCell(row, 0, "Số thứ tự", style);
        createCell(row, 1, "Họ và tên", style);
        createCell(row, 2, "Chức danh công việc", style);
        for (int i = 0; i <daysInMonth  ; i++) {
            createCell(row, i+3, ""+(i+1), style);
        }
        createCell(row,daysInMonth+4 , "Số ngày lương", style);
    }
    private void writeDataLines() {

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeight(14);
        style.setFont(font);
        List<Integer> daysWorking = listLocalDate.stream().map(localDate -> localDate.getDayOfMonth()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> holidays = listHolidays.stream().map(localDate -> localDate.getDayOfMonth()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Row row1 = sheet.createRow(1);
        Row row = sheet.createRow(3);
        createCell(row, 0,1, style);
        createCell(row, 1,user.getFullName(), style);
        createCell(row, 2,user.getJobName(), style);
        YearMonth yearMonthObject = YearMonth.of(this.year.intValue(), this.month.intValue());
        int daysInMonth = yearMonthObject .lengthOfMonth();
        int columnCount=3;

        for (int i = 1; i <daysInMonth+1  ; i++) {
            for(LocalDate localDate : listLocalDate) {
                if (daysWorking.contains(i)) {
                    createCell(row, columnCount++,"+", style);
                    break;
                }else if (holidays.contains(i)){
                    createCell(row, columnCount++,"L", style);
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    createCell(row, columnCount++, " ", style);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        createCell(row, columnCount+1, daysWorking.size()+holidays.size(), style);
    }

    private void createCell(Row row, int columnCount, Object value, CellStyle style) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnCount);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
        if (value instanceof Date) {
            cell.setCellValue((Date) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            cell.setCellValue((Boolean) value);
        }else if (value instanceof String){
            cell.setCellValue((String) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            cell.setCellValue((Integer) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof LocalDate) {
            cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf((LocalDate) value));
        }
        else {
            cell.setCellValue((Long) value);
        }
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }



    public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        writeHeaderLine();
        writeDataLines();

        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();

        outputStream.close();

    }
}
```

In my code. I just create a new excel and new sheet. I don't know how to use a given sheet to write data on them. Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: Online tutorials or the API docs have all the answers, you simply load a workbook by passing a file input stream or your file to the new XSSFWorkbook call like so `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(yourFile);` The API reference: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html specifically the constructor method `XSSFWorkbook(java.io.File file)` with the following description "Constructs a XSSFWorkbook object from a given file." you then perform sheet and cell actions as normal.

Comment: To access a sheet from the workboox we use `XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);` to get a row we use `Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);` and finally to get a cell we use `r.getCell(0, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);`

Comment: A useful reference: [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)